# Migrating part of my domain's services to Heroku, part on my VPS

Tags: vps, heroku

I have a virtual private server (VPS) with several services running on it -- most notably email and a Django web application with it's software stack (MySQL, Apache, etc.).  The VPS has a domain name assigned to it and an SSL certificate for it's assigned IP address.  I'd like to migrate the web application to Heroku using the same domain name.  I'd like to leave the other services (email especially) hosted on my VPS.

Is this possible?  Can I have the web application hosted on Heroku at, say, mydomain.com and have other services like email for erik@mydomain.com for the same domain hosted on my VPS through some DNS trickery?  Will I need to get a new SSL certificate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, and it doesn't require any "trickery".

Mail is directed towards your domain by way of DNS MX records. Just ensure that the MX records for your domain remain pointed at your VPS (it's likely that they already are configured to point to your VPS. If they're not, though, you need to create them), and then modify the A record for mydomain.com (and probably www.mydomain.com as well) to point to Heroku.

Regarding SSL, that's probably specific to Heroku. You'll need to look into how they handle certificate. It's likely that you'll need to have your existing cert re-issued after getting a CSR from Heroku.

Comment: Interesting.  DNS records are one of those things I touch once or twice in a blue moon, so I have to re-educate myself on them each time.  From what you say, it seems like a fairly routine change though .  Good to know.  Now, if only the migration was that easy...  Thanks.

Comment: Yep, fairly routine indeed. Be sure to read up on this stuff, though, before you make any changes. If you run into something else specific you want help with, feel free to throw another question at SF.